# MPU6050 with 3 I2C addresses?

Tags: microcontroller, i2c, micropython, raspberry-pi-pico

I have an MPU6050/GY-86 module connected to a Raspberry Pi Pico (MicroPython) via I2C on pins 0 (SDA) and 1 (SCL).

```python
from machine import Pin, I2C

i2c = I2C(0, sda = 0, scl = 1, freq = 400000)
devices = I2C.scan(i2c)
print(devices)
```

That's how I scan for devices. I expected to get an array containing `[104]` which would be the device's I2C address 0x68. Instead I got `[30, 104, 109]`. First and last number correspond to 0x1E (MCP9808, FXOS8700, HMC5883, LSM303, LSM303, 47L04/47C04/47L16/47C16) and 0x6D (PCA9685) which are devices I have don't even have.

Why is this happening? How can one device respond with 3 addresses?

Comment: Your code looks fine so far, perhaps I would try to use 100000 for frequency and repeat, and I have no idea whether the MPU6050 reacts on multiple addresses. But concerning your last question: Yes, a device can acknowledge on any number of addresses it wants.

Comment: @thebusybee I have tried 1000, 5000, 10000 and 100000 already. Same response every time. But it's good to know, that the addresses can be changed.

Comment: @OneMadGypsy I am using the pins denoted as 1 and 2 in the Pico pinout diagram, which both have the tag SDA and SCL. As far as I've undestood those are Pin(0) and Pin(1), right?

Comment: I wrote a [MPU6050 driver](https://github.com/OneMadGypsy/upy-motion) for the pico, long ago. You can use it if it helps you.

Comment: The module GY-86 module has 3 sensors the MPU6050, MS5611 and HMC5883L. What is strange is their addresses do not match the one provided by you.

Comment: That's good to know. So what you're saying is that each sensor has its own address and communicates it to the RP2040. But that still doesn't explain the wrong addresses i'm getting, and the device not reacting to any requests. The project has been on ice for a while now, due to other important deadlines approaching, but it's good I'm still getting answers to this :)